# Is there a way to do x++ but operating with larger numbers?

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to implement a method that returns a String of a matrix. The String should be

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

but it prints like

```
[0, 1, 0]
[3, 4, 3]
[6, 7, 6]
```

The problem is the next() method of the iterator i made.

```
@Override
public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    else if(columnIndex == dataset[rowIndex].length-1){
        return dataset[rowIndex++][columnIndex = 0];
    }else {
        return dataset[rowIndex][columnIndex++];
    }
}
```

It makes `columnIndex = 0` before `rowIndex++` is finished. I tried changing for `++rowIndex` but i was not able to achieve what I wanted. So, is there a way to do `columnIndex = 0` at the same time as `rowIndex++` works, and not `++rowIndex`?

Comment: I think that you're trying to be too clever. Just set a returnValue, adjust the indexes, and only then return. Don't rely on side-effects that much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such operation as post-assignment (similar to post-increment) is needed in the line:

```
return dataset[rowIndex++][columnIndex = 0];
```

that is, current value of `columnIndex` is returned and *after that* reset it to 0.

Such operation is not available for primitive `int` but class `AtomicInteger` in package `java.util.concurrent.atomic` provides similar functionality with method [`getAndSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndSet-int-)

So method `next()` may look as follows providing that the type of `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` have been changed to `AtomicInteger`:

```java
class Matrix implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private Integer[][] dataset;
    private AtomicInteger rowIndex;
    private AtomicInteger columnIndex;
    
    public Matrix(Integer[][] data) {
        this.dataset = data;
        rowIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
        columnIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return rowIndex.get() < dataset.length 
               && columnIndex.get() < dataset[rowIndex.get()].length;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        else if(columnIndex.get() == dataset[rowIndex.get()].length - 1) {
            return dataset[rowIndex.getAndIncrement()][columnIndex.getAndSet(0)];
        }

        return dataset[rowIndex.get()][columnIndex.getAndIncrement()];
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
Matrix m = new Matrix(new Integer[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3 && m.hasNext(); j++) {
        System.out.print(m.next() + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9
```

Comment: First of all thank you, I did not even know AtomicIntegers existed. Sencondly, I tried to implement the code but it is not working because 'rowindex.get()' in 'hasnext()' is null. I have the matrix class and iterator in different files, is the problem because of this?

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize the `rowIndex, columnIndex`, which should be the fields in the iterator class, as shown in the constructor above: `rowIndex = new AtomicInteger(0); columnIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);`

Comment: In the end I put it like tevemadar said so that I have to change less code. I was initializing them wrong, that is because it did not work. Anyway, much appreciated for your help. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you want hard-to-read magic, use integer division and modulo:

```
@Override
public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return [index / dataset[0].length][index++ % dataset[0].length];
}
```

where `index` starts from 0. This approach works with rectangular arrays only, but I assume it is a matrix in the mathematical sense, so all rows have the same number of elements.

Comment: Thank you! That is an interesting way to solve the problem.

Comment: Now that I tried to use it, an error occurs: .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3. Do you know what might it be?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it adding 1 or putting down to 0 the colums and rows before returning it